# Hi.. How to write java code to split the string?

Tags: java, regex, split

```
In my program a string is generated like this: Energie 670 kJ / 160 kcal 
So how to write split function in java code and the first keyword Energie should print
the outputs?
```

> **Input :**
>
> ```
>               Energie 670 kJ / 160 kcal
> ```
>
> **Expected output :**
>
> ```
>              1) Energie 670 kJ
>
>              2) Energie 160 kcal
> ```

If anyone have a solution to this problem or better way of going about splitting a
string twice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know it is a `String` and you want some operation done on it. Read the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. That way you would learn this and more. Stackoverflow is no substitute for API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is method in the String class for it

```
String[] split(String delimiter)
```

Use like this

```
String strs[] = str.split("/");
for (int i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(strs[i].trim());
}
```

But as others mentioned ,get comfortable reading the API ,most of the time you're likely to find what you are looking for .

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) api of String object as below:

```
String str = "Energie 670 kJ / 160 kcal";
String strs[] = str.split(" / ");//if you are expecting multiple space/tab etc use "\\s+/\\s+ instead of " / ""
for (int i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(strs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use appropriate method string.split() to split the string.

> String string = "Energie 670 kJ / 160 kcal";
>
> String[] parts = string.split("/");
>
> String part1 = parts[0].trim(); // Energie 670 kJ
>
> String part2 = parts[1].trim(); // 160 kcal

Comment: In part2,I should get output like this: Energie 160 kcal

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Energie 670 kJ / 160 kcal";
// remove the leading "Energie"
String stripped = s.replace("Energie", "").trim();
String[] parts = stripped.split("/");
// take what's left of the slash
String s1 = "Energie ".concat(parts[0].trim());
// take what's right of the slash
String s2 = "Energie ".concat(parts[1].trim());
// print both resultant strings
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringSplit {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
String testString = "670 kJ / 160 kcal";

System.out.println
   (java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("\\s+")));
```

}
}

```
   output : [670,kJ,/,160,kcal]
```

Get the reqiuered value from array. Instead of using whitespace you can also use '\' to split the string.